# How do I get updated FormView values when I process the form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

On ItemUpdating, I am able to retrieve field values, but I am not able to retrieve only updated values.

Is there a better way to do this than the method below?

```
protected void fwHotelDetails_ItemUpdating(Object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tbName = (TextBox)fwHotelDetails.Row.FindControl("input_name");
    MessageLabel.Text = "This works..." + tbName.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yea. Event handler's second parameter (**FormViewUpdateEventArgs** e) has following properties:

- Keys
- NewValues
- OldValues

More info on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formviewupdateeventargs.aspx)

Hope this helps